# proceed from server response "System.Collections.Generic.List"

Tags: curl

I am trying to download a webpage using php curl.

the php curl is working properly but the server is returning this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 15:07:21 GMT
Content-Length: 57
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RepZio.V2Model.Product]
```

If I type the same exact url in a browser the output is not System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RepZio.V2Model.Product] but is rather a normal html page.

How to proceed from System.Collections.Generic.List... to the html page?

Answer (score 0):

"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RepZio.V2Model.Product]" IS the content of the web page. If you were to open that URL up in the web browser and view source, that is what you would see.

It looks like the page on the end of that URL is not correctly writing the List contents to the page correctly.

Comment: that's the point. if i fetch the url in a browser it does not return System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RepZio.V2Model.Product] but a whole html web page. why the difference?